# Random Forest Model issues

Tags: r, random-forest

I ran Random Forest Model in R then now i call it to predict my dataset

```
predict.rf<-predict(layers.stack,random.forest, na.rm=T, type='response')
```

However it comes with one error as follow:

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('randomForest.formula', 'randomForest')"

Do anyone know how to fix this error pls?

Regards

Comment: The problem can only be solved with access to a sample of your data.

Comment: dear NelsonGon, thank you very much for your comment, i know it is hard for you to solve problems without data set however out dataset contains 88 satellite images which is over 200 GB so I could not upload the one here, very sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using two different R scripts - one for training, and another one for prediction. This error means that your prediction R script does not know about the `randomForest(.formula)` class.

You can fix it by simply importing the "randomForest" library into your prediction R script:

```
library("randomForest")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, yeah i did write the random forest model in separate file then calling it to run in the other file, i will adding library("randomForest") as you have just advised, cheers